# Split column over 2 columns and sum

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that looks like this  (Using SQL Server 2008 R2)

```
   [UNIQID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [SaleDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
   [Invoice] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
   [PDF File] [varchar](12) NULL,
   [Client] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
   [SaleStaff] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
   [Amount] [smallmoney] NOT NULL,
   [InvType] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
   [Paytype] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
   [remarks] [varchar](30) NULL
```

**The table have 9200 records in it**
I would like the Amount to be split over Paytype. I also managed to make it work, but it just seems very cumbersome.

This code works it first inserts all of `paytype` 1 into a Temptable. Then it inserts all of `Paytype` 2

````
```
{   {IF object_id('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
    CREATE TABLE #t
    ([UNIQID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SaleDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [PDF File] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [SaleStaff] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Paytype] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [xCash] varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    [Xcard] varchar(8) NOT NULL)


     insert into #t
     SELECT [UNIQID]
      ,[SaleDate]
      ,[invoice]
      ,[SaleStaff]
      ,[Paytype]
      ,[xcash] = convert(varchar(8),[Amount]) 
      ,[xCard] = ''
       FROM [dbo].[xxxSales]
       where (Paytype =1)

       insert into #t
       SELECT [UNIQID]
      ,[SaleDate]
      ,[Invoice]
      ,[SaleStaff]
      ,[Paytype]
      ,[xcash] =  ''
      ,[xCard] =convert(varchar(8),[Amount])
      FROM [dbo].[xxxSales]
       where (Paytype =2)

    Select max([UNIQID]) as id
    ,convert(varchar,[SaleDate],103) as saledate 
    ,max([PDF File]) as invoiceno 
    ,Max(dbo.fnStaff([SaleStaff])) as sid
    ,case PAyType when 1 then 'Cash'
                  When 2 then 'Card'
                  When 4 Then 'Order'
                  end as paytype 
    ,[xCash] as Cash
    ,[Xcard] as Card
    ,Sum(convert(Smallmoney,[xCash] ))OVER(partition BY PAyType)as CashTotal
    ,Sum(convert(Smallmoney,[xCaRD] ))OVER(partition BY PAyType)as CardTotal    
    from #t  
    where ([SaleDate] > '2019-01-01') and ([SaleDate] < '2019-01-12') 
    Group by  paytype,SaleDate,xCash,xcard  } ```
````

Last it selects from `temp table` any records between 2 dates

**It gives this result**

```
 id saledate    invoiceno   sid paytype Cash    Card    CashTotal   CardTotal


 1. 1248    08/01/2019  I191334 Unknown Cash    100.00      335.00  0.00
 2. 1251    08/01/2019  I191337 Unknown Cash    15.00       335.00  0.00
 3. 1250    08/01/2019  I191336 Unknown Cash    80.00       335.00  0.00
 4. 1257    10/01/2019  I191346 Unknown Cash    100.00      335.00  0.00
 5. 1255    10/01/2019  I191343 Unknown Cash    40.00       335.00  0.00
 6. 1243    08/01/2019  I191327 Unknown Card        80.00   0.00    195.00
 7. 1252    10/01/2019  I191338 Unknown Card        100.00  0.00    195.00
 8. 1256    10/01/2019  I191345 Unknown Card        15.00   0.00    195.00
```

The code should eventually go into a Stored Procedure, where the dates come
in as Parameters.

Some requested sample data:

```
UNIQID SaleDate Invoice PDF File Client SaleStaff Amount InvType    Paytype remarks
1241    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191324 I191324.PDF 0   0   100.00  1   1   
1242    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191326 I191326.PDF 0   0   80.00   1   1   
1243    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191327 I191327.PDF 0   0   80.00   1   2   
1244    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191330 I191330.PDF 0   0   15.00   1   1   
1245    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191331 I191331.PDF 0   0   100.00  1   1   
1246    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191332 I191332.PDF 0   0   80.00   1   1   
1248    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191334 I191334.PDF 0   0   100.00  1   1   
1249    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191335 I191335.PDF 0   0   80.00   1   1   
1250    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191336 I191336.PDF 0   0   80.00   1   1   
1251    2019-01-08 00:00:00 I191337 I191337.PDF 0   0   15.00   1   1   
1252    2019-01-10 00:00:00 I191338 I191338.PDF 0   0   100.00  1   2   
1253    2019-01-10 00:00:00 I191339 I191339.PDF 0   0   100.00  1   1   
1255    2019-01-10 00:00:00 I191343 I191343.PDF 0   0   40.00   1   1   
1256    2019-01-10 00:00:00 I191345 I191345.PDF 0   0   15.00   1   2   
1257    2019-01-10 00:00:00 I191346 I191346.PDF 0   0   100.00  1   1
```

Comment: Not clear.  What would be more helpful than a DDL dump would be to show us sample table data, along with the output you expect.

Comment: The output I would like it the list in the end it ust seems wrong that I take all the lines in to temptable

Comment: what is the expected output ? Please also show the sample data from your table. What you have shown is the query result

Comment: I don't see how the SQL you provided could result in that output. You have four columns of numeric results (cash, card, cash total, card total) but only three in your output. It feels like all you are wanting to do is pivot your `[amount]` by your `[paytype]` and then get a total for each paytype at the end (window functions are the right solution there).

Comment: The stuff you are looking at is copied straight out of SSMS and there is 4 Cash, card, cashTotal, cardTotal. it took me 4 hours to set this question up for this site and yet Birel ( God bless him) made 111 edits. If I had the money I would hire him just to my questions in here